# How create several View with one Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I want to build a shop application with several category and show product data in RecyclerView.

I pass data to RecyclerView like this :

```
   list = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new AdapterProduct(context, list);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    model = new ModelProductItem();

    model.setImage(R.drawable.image);
    model.setTitle("title");
    model.setPrice("price");

    list.add(model);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't want to create several activity for each product ,I want to handle this by one activity.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Intent` and `getIntent` we can moderate several view in one activity .

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list with categories and then filter out products by category in your recyclerview.

Check this https://www.ipragmatech.com/android-multiple-filters/

Comment: thank you but my purpose is not listing category.read question again